# DeadLock In Spring-Integration Application

Tags: spring, deadlock

I have a problem with a Legacy Application.
The application have two context, a Spring MVC context and a Spring Integration context.

The Spring MVC and the Spring Integration have two separates Entity Manager, but uses the same @Query repositories.

The application have and high load database access (for Read, Write and Updates) because receive millions of JMS messages all the days, and sometimes a DEADLOCK occurred.

If I put @Lock(OPTIMISTIC) in all the Querys in the repository, the problem is solved, but the Web application stop working “requiredTransactionException” says, this is normal because @Lock requires a Transaction and the MVC context don’t use transactions.

The question is, ¿How can I specify the @Lock in my Spring-Integration entity-manager-factory?

This is my Spring-Integration Entity Manager:

```
<bean id="entity-manager-factory" parent="entity-manager-factory-parent" depends-on="springJtaPlatformAdapter">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceInt" />
<property name="jpaPropertyMap">
    <map>
        <entry key="javax.persistence.transactionType" value="JTA" />
        <entry key="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta" />
        <entry key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="XXXXXXXXX (InternalClass, I Can't show name)" />
        <entry key="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
    </map>
</property>
```

EDIT:

The parent entity manager:

```
<bean id="entity-manager-factory-parent" abstract="true"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="packagesToScan" value="es.com.bbdd.entities" />
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    </bean>
</property>
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">SALES_SCHEMA</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

Comment: If it requires transaction management, add a transaction manager? Like: `<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
   <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entity-manager-factory" />
</bean>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i alredy have a Transaction Manager, is the "entity-manager-factory-parent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Thanks all the people for the answers.

The problem was that tablas are partitioned by foreign key reference , and the FK are not indexed , causing deadlocks by Oracle that blocks all the child table.

I have created all the indexes for the foreign keys and the problem is solved.